# Hashing trick for dimensionality reduction

Tags: nlp, dimensionality-reduction, apache-spark, tfidf, hashing-trick

I am building a model that uses TF-IDF NLP features in Spark Mllib. The [TF-IDF HashingTF function in Mllib](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#tf-idf) uses the 'hashing trick' to efficiently allocate terms to features.

My question is: **does the hashing trick work as an effective form of dimensionality reduction?** Since I can choose the number of features generated by the IDF function, can I choose a relatively small number of features (say, only 512 or 1024 features) and be confident that the allocation will retain meaningful properties across the data? I am using bi-grams in my TF-IDF so the natural number of terms in the vocabulary will be significantly more than 1024.

[Weinberger et al (2009)](https://alex.smola.org/papers/2009/Weinbergeretal09.pdf) seems to suggest that hashing is an effective form of dimensionality reduction. However, I'm interested if fellow practitioners find that it's a good option in the real world.

*Some additional context*: I am finding that training is very slow and believe it's due to the large number of columns (65,536). I have tried to use [ChiSqSelector](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#chisqselector) but that alone is taking hours to execute so doesn't improve things. The model I want to use can take a maximum of 4096 features, so I can't skip feature reduction.